# Code a polar function (Gabor) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, polar-coordinates, gabor-filter

How can I code this function in Matlab?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement this because:

1. If you have image processing toolbox there is a [built-in function for that](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/gabor.html).
2. If you don't, you can download an implementation from [Mathworks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44630-gabor-feature-extraction).
3. If for some reason, that's not good enough, you can copy the implementation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter#Example_implementations).

And finally, if it's an exercise that you should write yourself and external resources are forbidden - then you shouldn't ask it in the first place.

Good luck!